# for loop or use apply functions over a RODBC sql query

Tags: sql, r, for-loop, lapply, rodbc

Let's say I require a distinct count for each year with specific criteria as per where statement and x below being various years 2000 to 2016:

```
dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ID)
                  FROM table x
                  WHERE cust_STATUS_DESC like '%matured%'
                  and YEAR(END_DATE) in ("x") ") )
```

How do I do this using a for loop or apply function?

Comment: Try something like `res <- lapply(2010:2015, function(x) dbGetQuery(conn, paste("SELECT .... in", x ")")`

Comment: I am getting the  Error: unexpected string constant in:

Comment: Edit your post with more detail, paste your code, and error message.